# Concatenate a list to the end of paths - Powershell

Tags: windows, list, powershell, iteration, concatenation

I have a list of paths and a list of executables files that I need to concatenate together and look for each file under each said path. However, when I run my code, I am seeing that the executables are not being concatenated, just added as a new line. Additionally, it is only being added to the last object in the list. See code, output, and desired output below:

Code:

```
   $final_paths = @();

   $paths = @("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15", "C:\Program Files\Microsoft 
   Office Servers\OFFICE15");

   $exes = @("MSOCF.DLL", "access.exe", "word.exe", "wordCnv.exe", "WordViewer.exe", "Excel.exe", "ExcelCnv.exe", "ExcelViewer.exe", "PowerPoint.exe", 
  "PowerPointViewer.exe", "PowerPointCnv.exe", "Publisher.exe", "Project.exe", "OneNote.exe", "InfoPath.exe Groove.exe", "FrontPage.exe", 
  "SharePointDesigner.exe", "Visio.exe", "VisioViewer.exe", "Lync.exeOutlook.exe", "WINPROJ.EXE")

  foreach ($exe in $exes)
  {
    $final_paths += $paths"\$exe";
    write-output $final_paths;
  }

  foreach ($found_path in $final_paths)
  {
    $file = Get-Item -Path $found_path -ErrorAction Ignore;
    Write-Output $file
```

Sample Output:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
Excel.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
ExcelCnv.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
ExcelViewer.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
PowerPoint.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
PowerPointViewer.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
PowerPointCnv.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
Publisher.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
Project.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
OneNote.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
InfoPath.exe Groove.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
FrontPage.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
SharePointDesigner.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
Visio.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
VisioViewer.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
Lync.exeOutlook.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15        
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
WINPROJ 
...
...
...
you get the idea
```

Desired Output:

I simply want nothing but the file name returned as a string, like so:

`WIINPROJ`

Comment: you are adding one string to an ARRAY of strings. that will give you what you got ... an array with the new string added to the end. [*grin*] ///// you need to iterate thru BOTH arrays ... and otta use `Join-Path` instead of string concatenation.

Comment: BTW, what's the use of testing for an .exe in two different paths if all you want as output is the file **name** of the exe (withtout that path)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why try and concatenate paths into full names and then try to figure out using `Get-Item` if that file exists or not?

Using [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) things would be a lot easier, because

1. it can handle an **array** of folder paths in the `-Path` parameter
2. you get only FileInfo objects returned for the specific files you filter through a `Where-Object` clause so you don't need to check their existance afterwards
3. you get a lot more information than just the file name, so you can decide later what it is exactly you want in the output

```
$paths = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15', 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15'
$exes  = 'MSOCF.DLL', 'access.exe', 'word.exe', 'wordCnv.exe', 'WordViewer.exe', 'Excel.exe', 'ExcelCnv.exe', 'ExcelViewer.exe', 'PowerPoint.exe', 
         'PowerPointViewer.exe', 'PowerPointCnv.exe', 'Publisher.exe', 'Project.exe', 'OneNote.exe', 'InfoPath.exe Groove.exe', 'FrontPage.exe', 
         'SharePointDesigner.exe', 'Visio.exe', 'VisioViewer.exe', 'Lync.exeOutlook.exe', 'WINPROJ.EXE'

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $paths -File | Where-Object { $exes -contains $_.Name }
```

Now you decide what property you want to retrieve from the $files collection

```
# just the Name?
$files.Name | Select-Object -Unique  # unique in case you found the same exe in both folders

# the Fullname perhaps?
$files.FullName
```

Comment: This is returning: `Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.`

Comment: @cynicalswan77 Ouch.. are you using an ancient PowerShell version maybe? If you are, try upgrading to at least version 3.0. If that's not possible, you need to add an extra test in the Where-Object clause `{ !$_.PSIsContainer -and $exes -contains $_.Name }`. Then remove the `-File` switch.

Comment: Sorry, false alarm. The paths were dir objects, not strings. Once I converted, it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-6.0) method from `System.IO` for this:

```
$finalPaths = foreach($path in $paths)
{
    foreach($exe in $exes)
    {
        Get-Item ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($path, $exe)) -EA Ignore
    }
}

$finalPaths.Name # => Should be the Names of the files found
```

Alternatively, as [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) suggested in his comment, you can use [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7.2) to achieve the same result:

```
$finalPaths = foreach($path in $paths)
{
    foreach($exe in $exes)
    {
        Get-Item (Join-Path $path -ChildPath $exe) -EA Ignore
    }
}
```